# how to edit file on remote host container where kubernetes pod is created

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code

In my scenario, our package from gitlab is already implemented pipeline to deploy kubernetes pod on remote host server. If I want to edit/open folder on kubernetes pod of the container using vscode, is it doable for vscode?

Comment: There is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025213/how-can-i-browse-a-persistent-volume-in-kubernetes-and-edit-files-with-gui

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I browse a persistent volume in kubernetes and edit files with GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025213/how-can-i-browse-a-persistent-volume-in-kubernetes-and-edit-files-with-gui)

Answer (score 1):

Official Visual Studio Code documentation [shows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container#_attach-to-a-container-in-a-kubernetes-cluster) how to attach to a running container, also [inside Kubernetes cluster](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container#_attach-to-a-container-in-a-kubernetes-cluster).

---

However, using [Persisent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) may be a better approach.

Files modified in a "local" directory are simultaneously modified in attached volume (this is a bit more complicated but lets go with that for the sake of example), and they persist between pod restarts.